# ZK : How to change <html> background-color

Tags: html, css, zk

I want to change the whole background color in CSS. Usually in HTML we just apply style to `<html>` tag like this :

```
<html style="background-color:black;">
    <body>
       ...
    </body>
</html>
```

But in ZK `.zul` file, the code is usually like this :

```
<zk>
   <div>
    ...
   </div>
</zk>
```

There is no `<html>` tag. Is there any way to change the whole background-color in ZK ? I've tried the `.z-page` but it's limited to everything under `<zK>` component only and not the whole page.

Comment: Can you not use a style sheet opposed to in-line?

Comment: simply use `zk { background: #fff; }` to change the background color

Answer (score 1):

You can use **type selector** to change the background color of all the elements.

```
/* Add all the elements here */
div, span, table, ... {
    background: #fff;
}
```

Add this at the start of your styles, otherwise it'll override the styles of other elements.

You can also use `zk` to style

```
zk {
    background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Using the asterisk approach will destroy default styling for buttons and transparent elements such as spans.

Answer (score 1):

You can try jQuery for this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("html").css("background-color","black");
});
```

If jQuery won't help you, please check the [link](http://forum.zkoss.org/question/40329/how-to-change-background-page/) it might add some light on your issue. Hope this helps.

```
<zk>
    <window border="3d">
        <style>
            body { background-color: #EBEBEB; }
        </style>
    </window>
</zk>
```

Comment: Even though your answer is not the best solution, I don't believe it deserved a down-vote.  By using jQuery there would be a delay in applying the styling and also the page would not display as desired if JS were disabled.  Additionally this could have be done using vanilla JS removing the need for a heavy JavaScript library.  Either way a CSS only approach would be a better fit. [ +1 to counter the down-vote ]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like although zk technically don't have the `<html>` tag inside the `.zul` file, ( in my opinion ) the client browser translate the `.zul` file from like this :-

```
<zk>
  <div>
    ...
  </div>
</zk>
```

into this structure as inspected via Inspect Element in Google Chrome.

```
<html>
    <body>
       ...
    </body>
</html>
```

So yeah, we can't apply inline style directly into `<html>`. And we need to use the **type selector** as suggested by @Tushar, simply by using external css which contain this block.

```
html {
    background-color : black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your CSS rules inside `<style>...</style>` tags:

```
<zk>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: black;
        }
    </style>
    ....
    ....
    ....

</zk>
```

Read [ZK CSS Classes and Styles](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Reference/Theming_and_Styling/CSS_Classes_and_Styles).

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the your css, or in a style tag:

> body {
> background-color: white
> }